# Rendering scenes into bufferedimage before painting it into screen?

Tags: java, swing

I am thinking of some different ways of rendering the game into the screen.
I've currently working on a indie game and usually I just paint the textures on the screen right away:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        for(int i=0;i<textures.size;i++){
             g.drawImage(texture.get(i).getTexture(),texture.get(i).getX(), texture.get(i).getY(), null)
        }
    }
```

But this is just an example. The problem with this is that if you have too many textures, you might start noticing some flickering or the process of drawing because when the `g.drawImage` is called, it paints the texture into the screen right after.

So I've though of a solution however I am not sure if it's a good way of doing it.
What I've done is instead of painting the textures into the screen, I simply draw them into the `BufferedImage`. After that, I simply draw the `BufferedImage` into the screen.

Here is an example:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
          g.drawImage(bufferRender(), 0, 0, null);
    }
    public BufferedImage bufferRender(){
          BufferedImage render = new BufferedImage(Main.window.getWidth(), Main.window.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
          Graphics g = render.getGraphics();
          for(int i=0;i<textures.size;i++){
               g.drawImage(texture.get(i).getTexture(),texture.get(i).getX(), texture.get(i).getY(), null)
          }
          return render;
    }
```

Now the question is... Is it a fine way of doing this?

Comment: *"Is it a fine way of doing this?"* Yes. It would be the standard way to draw a set backdrop. One tip though: `g.drawImage(bufferRender(), 0, 0, null);` 1) That should be preceded by `super.paintComponent(g);` 2) Best it should be `g.drawImage(bufferRender(), 0, 0, this);` to take advantage of the `ImageObserver` that every `JComponent` implements.

Comment: You're re-creating the image with each paintComponent call, and that can slow things down. If possible, try to do as much drawing once and in advance, and then within paintComponent simply draw the pre-made images. Also, you are not disposing of the Graphics object that you get from the BufferedImage, and you should dispose of it after you're done with it (within `bufferRender()`).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: it looks like his second code snippet will be no faster than the first, since all he's doing is refactoring the paintComponent method, no?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"all he's doing is refactoring the paintComponent method, no?"* Oh.. right you are. :P That image should only be generated once if it does not change. If it (the background) is constantly changing, it makes no sense to draw to an image in the rendering chain.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Swing components are already double buffered. Having said that, if you could use a `BufferedImage` to contain the "static" graphics element, which would mean you don't have to repaint all those elements which aren't changing between frames, this would help speed things up